# Find a post in Facebook newsfeed based on the title

Tags: facebook

Is there any possibility to get a post based on its title or contents? I partially read a post last week, now I want to read it again. How do I find it again from my account?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use Facebook search.

https://www.facebook.com/search/str/concrete%2Bblocks/stories-keyword/me/pages-liked/stories/intersect

The above should find all posts with "concrete blocks" mentioned it that are also pages that you like

https://www.facebook.com/search/str/concrete%2Bblocks/stories-keyword/stories-feed

This should give you friends and groups